# How to store the readStream files of Node.js into Redis and also how to retrieve the stored readStream files from Redis?

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis, nodejs-stream, redis-cache

I tried converting the readStream (Image) to string and then storing it in Redis. Then retrieving the string from Redis and converting it back to readStream. But it didn't work out.

```
function getFile(fileKey) {
  console.log(fileKey);
  const downloadParams = {
    Key: fileKey,
    Bucket: bucketName,
  };

  return s3.getObject(downloadParams).createReadStream();
}

exports.getFile = getFile;
```

For converting stream to string I'm using stream-to-string. It gets converted and stored in Redis.

```
const { getFile } = require("../s3");
const redis = require("redis");

const client = redis.createClient();

var toString = require("stream-to-string");

exports.getFileFromS3Controller = async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params);
  const path = req.params.path;
  const key = req.params.key;
  const readStream = getFile(path + "/" + key);

  toString(readStream).then(function (msg) {
    // Set data to Redis
    client.setex(key, 3600, msg);
  });

  readStream.pipe(res);
};
```

On Retrieving from the Redis I am not getting it.

```
const redis = require("redis");
const client = redis.createClient(null, null, { detect_buffers: true });
const Readable = require("stream").Readable;

// Cache middleware
function cache(req, res, next) {
  const { path, key } = req.params;

  client.get(key, (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    if (data !== null) {
      var s = new Readable();
      s.push(data);
      s.push(null);
      s.pipe(res);
    } else {
      next();
    }
  });
}

router.get("/:path/:key", cache, getFileFromS3Controller);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calling next. Another mistake is that the stream is not being saved anywhere in the req so you can access later from the controller. From what I see you are writing it directly in res which is a problem because after this you cannot use res anymore to send anything else.

Here it is the code (not tested)

```
exports.getFileFromS3Controller = (req, res) => {
  if (req.fileStream) {
      req.fileStream.pipe(res);
      return
  }

  console.log(req.params);
  const path = req.params.path;
  const key = req.params.key;
  const readStream = getFile(path + "/" + key);

  toString(readStream).then(function (msg) {
      // Set data to Redis
      client.setex(key, 3600, msg);

      // Conver string to readable
      const readable = new Readable();
      readable.push(msg);
      readable.push(null);
      readable.pipe(res);
  });
};

function cache(req, res, next) {
    const { path, key } = req.params;

    client.get(key, (err, data) => {
        if (err) throw err;

        if (data !== null) {
            var s = new Readable();
            s.push(data);
            s.push(null);

            req.fileStream = s;
        }

        next();
    });
}
```

**Edit** I fixed a mistake in my answer because a Readable stream cannot be rewinded.

Comment: I corrected the mistakes, which you pointed out but still, no image is shown on retrieval.

Comment: @ShakkirMoulana Please try it again as I overlooked a detail related to Readable. Also make sure that getFile is synchronous. If it is  Promise or async function you must await.

Comment: I tried again, still not working. If I use readStream.pipe(res), I am getting the image. But after converting readStream to string and then converting back to readable, is not working. I think there is some issue in the conversion part.

Comment: Your input has helped me. Thank you. 
Instead of converting string to stream and vice-versa, I used redis-wstream and redis-rstream module. It's working now.

Comment: @ShakkirMoulana If my answer was helpful please accept it.